# JQuery Mobile creates wrong HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm currently developing a PhoneGap Application for Android using JQuery Mobile.
All i want, is to dynamically change the header text of a collapsible:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="collapse">
   <h3>I'm a header</h3>
   <p>I'm the collapsible content</p>
</div>
```

That code is from demos.jquerymobile.com. Chrome DevTools gives me the following html for this example:
http://de.tinypic.com/r/2uf982p/8

For any reason, if i copy exactly the same code to my index.html and run it, chrome DevTools gives me the following html:
http://de.tinypic.com/r/2wohcf7/8

Why are there different html codes?

I actually can change the header's text by

```
$("#collapse").text("new text");
```

but then it looses all the styling and also

```
$("#collapse").trigger('create').
```

doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep all the styling of the widget, the easiest way is to **[destroy the widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#method-destroy)**, change the heading text and then re-initialize the widget:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="collapse">
   <h3 id="collapse-header">I'm a header</h3>
   <p>I'm the collapsible content</p>
</div>

$("#collapse").collapsible( "destroy" );
$('#collapse-header').text('I\'m a new header!');
$("#collapse").collapsible();
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7negvxsL/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the `<h3>` tag of the div itself. Consider what you've changed:

`$("#collapse").text("new text");`

This replaces *all* of the text within the collapse id. What you need to do instead is grab the value of the header itself, which can be done as follows:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="collapse">
   <h3 id="collapse-header">I'm a header</h3>
   <p>I'm the collapsible content</p>
</div>
<script>
    $('#collapse-header').text('I\'m a new header!');
</script>
```

Comment: This also changes the text, but again all the styling get's lost

Comment: I don't seem to have that problem. Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7negvxsL/) for an example. If you're still having problems, I'd recommend creating one yourself so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Try to put the jQuery code in your fiddle in the external .js. Then all the styling is lost. But in my case, it doesn't matter, where i write the jQuery code, it always look crappy after changing it

Comment: Try to put what in the external js? All of the libraries that you need are loaded. Any other changes should be done within the fiddle itself.